# Defining an Azure Board query that tracks work I have performed during current sprint - at any given time within that sprint

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

I am trying to come up with  n Azure Board query to return the work I have performed during current sprint - which I am vaguely defining as:

```
Work In Current Sprint = [A] + [B]
```

where
**A** = work items where I completed development stage (or was decided at some point work is irrelevant) and
**B** = work items I created in current sprint, not necessarily assign to me nor my team (I spent time investigating an issue, and ended up, for instance, finding a bug, so I want this included in this "report").

The closest I could get is the query blow. Problem is it is still not quite accurate, since with regards to items I created during this sprint - I could not find a way to filter created items in this sprint only - results are showing up work items that CURRENTLY BELONG to current sprint, but not necessarily created in current sprint. The only way I see I can achieve what I want is using CreatedBy - but this only provides a "hardcoded" date range offset, at any given time. If I use an offset of 14 days backwards, running query at the last day of the sprint (considering a 2 week sprint duration) should work, but running the query at any day before that, during the sprint, will return stuff created in previous sprints.

I want this query to help me track "work I have performed during current sprint" (as defined above) at any given day within the sprint.

Any better ideas ?

[image]

Comment: Hi @Veverke, does the answer below help you? If not, please kindly tell your requirement. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You could use custom date in 'create date' to limit the work item.
[image]

And I notice you use 'work items and direct links', then you need set filters for 'Filters for linked work items' part(as you needed, like iteration path etc.). Otherwise it may return linked work item that belong to other iterations, according to the filled filter, like something belows:
[image]

I hope it could help.

Comment: Hardcoding a date does not help me. I need this to be correct at any given time within Current Sprint. So I can't hardcode  absolute dates. Neither using the Created Date expressions help, because they, again, are hardcoded to this or that specific days interval. As days goes by, the number of days I want to look backwards in current sprint - increase.

Comment: As you said, there is not an accurate method in UI now support your requirement. But you could try to write script by using the rest api [ Get Wiql](Wiql - Get - REST API (Azure DevOps Work Item Tracking) | Microsoft Learn) get the for example 'currentiteration -14 days', input the variable into the query as created date. Then you are expected to get the accurate value. Thanks.